# Replace every comma by mask

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string that look like this:

```
18 S, 95,food,19 S, 48,food,19 S,3 400,auto repair
```

I need it to look like this:

```
18 S – 95 $ – food 
19 S – 48 $ – food 
19 S – 3 400 $ – auto repair
```

I tried to:

```
answer.toString().replace(/([^,],[^,]*?,[^,]*?),/g, '$1\n').replace(/,/g, ' – ');
```

I just started with my telegram bot with google sheets and its very hard for me to understand how .replace properly work with the masks like  "/([^,]...". If you also know a good topic about .replace masks syntax with examples I would be very grateful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you run that in console it outputs what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of capturing all the three `,` into a single capturing group you can capture them as three separate groups and add the value in desired format before or after the particular group

```
([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)(?:,|$)
```

[image]

```js
let str = `18 S, 95,food,19 S, 48,food,19 S,3 400,auto repair`

let final = str.replace(/([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)(?:,|$)/g, '$1 - $2 $ - $3\n')

console.log(final)
```